# manually authenticate kaggle api

Tags: python, kaggle

One of these combinations should work for setting the account info to download a kaggle dataset. Placing the json file in azure isn't working so was trying this

```
import kaggle
api=kaggle.KaggleApi()
api.CONFIG_NAME_USER='abc'
api.CONFIG_NAME_KEY='xyz'
api.read_config_environment({"username":"abc","key":"xyz"})
api.authenticate()
api.competition_download_files('dataset_name')
```

EDIT:
This is source and I'be tried setting all of these variables manually

`config_data = self.read_config_environment(config_data)`

```
    # Step 2: if credentials were not in env read in configuration file
    if self.CONFIG_NAME_USER not in config_data \
            or self.CONFIG_NAME_KEY not in config_data:
        if os.path.exists(self.config):
            config_data = self.read_config_file(config_data)
        else:
            raise IOError('Could not find {}. Make sure it\'s located in'
                          ' {}. Or use the environment method.'.format(
                              self.config_file, self.config_dir))
```